# How to deploy Hyperledger Composer to "Azure Hyperledger Single Member Blockchain"?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I found the guideline to deploy Hyperledger Fabric to "Azure Hyperledger Single Member Blockchain" [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyperledger-Fabric-Single-2324cecb) but I can't deploy my Composer network.

I don't found any guideline to do it.

Does anyone have the same problem with me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

cool. Next, go ahead and install Hyperledger Composer and its tooling, see doc link here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer//installing/development-tools.html

It describes all of the pre-requisites you need to set up on your Development VM (that interacts with your Fabric network).

You'll then need to gather the names or IP addresses of your Fabric nodes like CA, orderer etc. and you will provide that information to the connection profiles https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/connectionprofile.html you define, as part of your business network card creation https://hyperledger.github.io/composer//managing/id-cards-playground  - this is so that your Admins and Composer participants can connect/deploy/update/interact with the runtime Fabric network and configured nodes, that you have configured on Azure.

best wishes !

Comment: I have 2 questions:
1. Do I need install Hyperledger Composer and its tooling in CA and orderer VM or just install in all peers?

2. I get the error `Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed parsing HTTP/2` 
do I need enable something like firewall in Azure?

Thank you very much for the anwser

Comment: That error happen when I try run `composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -n mynetwork`

Comment: 1) Composer runtime gets installed on the peer (there's one, if you've deployed the developer framework for the Single Org tutorial). The Fabric also needs to be up and running - you can check that the CONTAINERS are up and running using `docker ps` (to see if the peer, ca, orderer nodes are running eg `ca.org1.example.com`, `peer0.org1.example.com` - if you follow the tutorial instructions carefully, it should work (it has been working for some time weeks now) - I would definitely check your connection profile information is correct - you can copy the complete profile from the tutorial

Comment: 2) You are running all the containers locally for this tutorial inside your virtual environment - you definitely don't need to enable a firewall, for this to work - unless you meant 'disable' ?

Comment: CA status is `Restarting`, all other is `Up`
Here is my connection.json:
`{"type":"hlfv1","name":"fabric-network","orderers":[{"url":"grpc://regititjn.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:3001"}],"ca":{"url":"http://regititjn.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:3000","name":"regititjn.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com"},"peers":[{"requestURL":"grpc://regititjn.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:3002","eventURL":"grpc://regititjn.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:3003"}],"keyValStore":"${HOME}/.composer-credentials","channel":"composerchannel","mspID":"Org1MSP","timeout":"300"}`
Can you help me check

Comment: I don't know the port is correct or not, but I can use this port to remote (ssh) to the vm machine. Thanks you very much for quick answer. Again the error I get is `Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed parsing HTTP/2`

Comment: I paste the connection here to easier to read: http://plnkr.co/edit/nXnWc0UNGfNSwr6bEhSw?p=preview

Comment: you don't need `"keyValSto‌​re":"${HOME}/.compos‌​er-credentials", ` in your profile so remove it. See also single org example in docs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org.html  - the ports in your environment are presumably correct (in the tutorial link, they are default for a local VM). I would also do a `docker ps` to ensure all your nodes are up and that your resolution of names works.